# Read time from excel sheet using xlrd, in time format and not in float

Tags: python, datetime, floating-point, xlrd

I am trying to read some data from a excel file. One of the columns has time values in the format HH:MM:SS. Xlrd reads this time and converts it into float. I have another time values in my python file which I want to compare with the excel-imported time values. I am not able to do that as long as one of them is a "time" and the other is a "float". Any suggestions?

This is how my excel file looks like -

```
Time    L_6_1   PW_6_1  Tc_6_1  Te_6_1

0:00:00 10000   500 290 270
1:00:00 10000   600 290 270
2:00:00 10000   700 290 270
3:00:00 10000   800 290 270
4:00:00 10000   900 290 270
```

And this is how I am reading this data -

```
wb=xlrd.open_workbook('datasheet.xls')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
timerange=sh.col_values(0)
print timerange
```

This is the output with float values for time -

```
[u'Time', 0.0, 0.041666666666666664, 0.083333333333333301, 0.125, 0.166666666666
66699, 0.20833333333333301, 0.25, 0.29166666666666702, 0.33333333333333298, 0.37
5, 0.41666666666666702, 0.45833333333333298, 0.5, 0.54166666666666696, 0.5833333
3333333304, 0.625, 0.66666666666666696, 0.70833333333333304, 0.75, 0.79166666666
666696, 0.83333333333333304, 0.875, 0.91666666666666696, 0.95833333333333304]
```

Comment: Could you post a part of the data and what you have tried?

Comment: I just edited the question, including the data and part of my code.

Comment: https://scraperwiki.com/docs/python/python_excel_guide/. Here, they have give how to extract date from excel(search for 'datetime'), simillarly, you can do it for time values.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Excel stores times as fractions of a day.  You can convert this to a Python time as follows:

```
from datetime import time

x = excel_time # a float
x = int(x * 24 * 3600) # convert to number of seconds
my_time = time(x//3600, (x%3600)//60, x%60) # hours, minutes, seconds
```

If you need more precision, you can get it by converting to milliseconds or microseconds and creating a time that way.

Answer (score 23):

The xlrd library has a built-in, xldate_as_tuple() function for getting you most of the way there:

```
import xlrd
from datetime import time
wb=xlrd.open_workbook('datasheet.xls')

date_values = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(cell_with_excel_time, wb.datemode)  

# date_values is now a tuple with the values: (year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds),
# so you just need to pass the last 3 to the time() function.
time_value = time(*date_values[3:])
```

Comment: Best answer! I always prefer to use existing code then re-inventing the wheel

Answer (score 1):

```
    def convert_excel_time(t, hour24=True):
        if t > 1:
            t = t%1
        seconds = round(t*86400)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
        hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
        if hour24:
            if hours > 12:
                hours -= 12
                return "%d:%d:%d PM" % (hours, minutes, seconds)
            else:
                return "%d:%d:%d AM" % (hours, minutes, seconds)
        return "%d:%d:%d" % (hours, minutes, seconds)


print convert_excel_time(0.400983796)
print convert_excel_time(0.900983796, hour24=False)
print convert_excel_time(0.4006944444444)
print convert_excel_time(1.4006944444444)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the inbuilt function of xlrd "xldate_as_datetime" (in accordance with the notification by Troy)

```
import xlrd
from datetime import time
wb=xlrd.open_workbook('datasheet.xls')

date_values = xlrd.xldate_as_datetime(cell_with_excel_time, wb.datemode)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #outage read data
outage_sheet =workbook2.sheet_by_index(day)
#str outage
outage =outage_sheet.cell_value(141,3)

#convert float time to hh:mm formate
x = int(outage*24*3600)
outage_a= time(x//3600,(x%3600)//60)
```

Here i am taking the float value outage and converting it to the HH:SS format

Comment: It's helpful if you also explain what your code is doing. This way you'll get more upvotes and your answer will be useful to people searching on Stack Overflow