# Time (HH:MM:SS) in Excel is converted to decimal value in openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to run the following code :

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("/Users/kakkar/Downloads/TRADEBOOK ALL-EQ 01-01-2016 TO 04-02-2017.xlsx")
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('TRADEBOOK')
print(sheet.cell(row=15, column=3).value)
print(sheet.cell(row=15, column=3).internal_value)
```

In the input Excel file, column 3 contains the time value `10:47:49`. This is being treated in openpyxl as the floating-point value `0.449872685185185`.

How can I get the time value in the form `HH:MM:SS`?

Comment: In the future, please actually state your question, instead of just showing code. I've edited your answer to do this, and to remove the personal information (including your account number) contained in the screenshots.

Comment: You are deliberately obfuscating the question. openpyxl will return a time value but you are asking for the Excel representation which is a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel stores time (and date) values as floating-point numbers. The whole number is the number of days since the epoch (1 Jan 1970), while the remainder is the portion of the day.

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17143367/1589422) that can help you get the hours, minutes, and seconds out of the value, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23432565/1589422) might be better for getting the answer without writing code (it uses the xlrd library).

Answer (score 0):

the .internal_value of 10:47:49 (HH:MM:SS) **IS** 0.449872685185185, so its OK.

Please give as the following output:

```
cell = sheet['C15']
print('cell=\t%s\n\ttype=%s\n\t.number_format=%s;\n\t.value=%s;\n\t.internal_value=%s;' % (cell,str(type(cell.value)),cell.number_format,cell.value,cell.internal_value) )
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 4.3.3.2***